# I need to find fixed leftside 100% height menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm Matthew and i'm new here. I need to find a menu which looks like that here:
http://noblebank.pl/ (leftmenu)
I have searched it a half day and i got no more ideas how to find something like that :)
I will be grateful for any help :)

**EDIT:**
The most important thing in this menu is sliding submenu after clicking his parent and submenu should be also made in 100% height.

Comment: This is a fixed sidebar. look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U8HGz/1/

Comment: Just inspect the sidebar element with Firebug or equivalent and see how they did it.

Answer (score 2):

I made a little example for you, basicly you need a width, position and 100% height

```
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:200px;
```

To position it you can set the following options

```
left:0;
bottom:0;
top:0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XSxqA/

Comment: This is cool. I've just even tried to do something by myself but the most important thing in this menu is sliding submenu after clicking his parent and submenu should be also made in 100% height.

Comment: You'll need to use jQuery for that, have a look at `animate` - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    Fixed menu
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    Main content
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above the html and bellow the css

http://jsfiddle.net/LcWfB/

```css
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:150px;
    left:0;
    top:0
}
#main{
    margin-left:150px;
}
```